# Whatsapp Icon Clip for send file

Tags: java, android, layout, sendfile

I'm doing a similar app to WhatsApp, and I have to send images and documents. I would like to do it like on WhatsApp.

Clicking the clip's clip will open a **menu** in which you can choose what to send.
How could I do it?

Help me, please

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is a wide question. But here goes my opinion for you to implement it fast.

1. Add options menu to your application. (3 vertical dots at the corner)
2. Create a fragment/pop-up/menu with your custom layout(icons, buttons
       etc...) that starts from #1
3. Add necessary methods to each button/icon.

OR

1. Create a button and put it into your app's ToolBar yourself.
2. Open a fragment/pop-up from onClick of that button.
3. Add necessary methods to each button/icon on that fragment/pop-up

Hopefully these line of thought helps. You can search for each step online.